Failed to start a tensorboard session
i have a problem with my tensorboard when i do ctrl+shift+p to launch my tensorboard in vscode here is the error it shows me:
Failed to start a TensorBoard session due to the following error:Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for TensorBoard to launch.
Failed to start a TensorBoard session due to the following error:Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for TensorBoard to launch.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
Please see how to ask.
minimal reproducible example
